# xcode EGODatabase update

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I am trying to do a simple update to a sqlite database using EGODatabase and although the code runs the update does not occur?

```
 NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TEST", nil];

 EGODatabase *database = [EGODatabase databaseWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_USBV1.sqlite3"]];

 [database executeQuery:@"update users set locked = 0 where UID = ?" parameters:params ];
```

I saw on previous post that must copy the db to the users directory which i am doing as below;

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_USBV1.sqlite3"];
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
  NSError *error = nil;
  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db_USBV1" ofType:@"sqlite3"] toPath:filePath error:&error];
 }
 [fileManager release];
```

But update is not occurring.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: for future reference, when inserting code, highlite it and click on the 0101 icon just above the text box -- it makes the code readable :)

Comment: to your issue, what is the value of error after the copyItemAtPath and what is the result of [database executeQuery:...]?

Comment: IOW, where is your 'EGODatabaseResult* result'?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers. I was still attempting to work with the file in the bundle and not the file that was copied.